# U-boot is not running from SD card?

Tags: kernel, u-boot, texas-instruments

I am trying to build u-boot (2018 version) for AM3352 processor (on customized board) and boot it from SD-card. I am able to compile it but when i try to boot, it does not show anything on the screen. how can i go from here to find what is it i am doing wrong?

I have confirmed the hardware and the jumper setting by running the old version of u-boot(2013) which was build by someone else long ago.

The u-boot is build with latest TI SDK 5.03.00.07 version

Please suggest me the next to step to figure out the problem.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**:

The procedure followed is
1. Download TI-SDK 5.03.0.07 version
2. Build the u-boot with defconfig - tisdk_am335x-evm_defconfig and UBOOT_MACHINE- am335x_evm_config

3. Generated MLO and u-boot.img
4. Copied MLO and u-boot.img to SD card which is a bootable SD-card with which older u-boot was being booted
5. When i switch on the board connected with serial interface, i do not see any messages on the console. If i remove the SD-card and switch on, i do see the charcer 'CCCCCCCC' getting displayed which says the boot configuration for SD-card is correct. 
   My understanding is that, if the MLO is not being detected on i would expect 'CCC...' to be displayed.

The processor is TI's AM3352 which is connected with peripherals. I am not configuring the peripherals in the first step as my first step is to see something on the console. It can throw error messages for uninitialized peripherals which i am not bothered of at this point of time.

I am doing this for the first time so i do not know how to proceed. please suggest.

Comment: Please provide a log of how and what you're writing to your SD card and what platform specifically you're using.

Comment: @Tom Rini. I have added the procedure i am following in the question. please check and see if you can help me.